# enviar a variavel de javascript para php

Tags: php, javascript

Eu tenho esta variavel sum1 em javascript e gostaria de a enviar para o php como posso fazer isto ?

**JS**

```
var sum1 = 0.0;
$('.class_nao_pago').each(function()
{
    sum1 += parseFloat($(this).text());
```

**PHP**

```
echo $sum1
```

Comment: submit ou ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só vai conseguir fazer isso se chamar uma página via AJAX (por post ou get) ou então criar um form na sua html principal que envia esta variável para uma página PHP.

Essa integração que você esta tentando realizar não tem como acontecer.

Veja este exemplo:

```
var sum1 = 0.0
$('.class_nao_pago').each(function()
{
    sum1 += parseFloat($(this).text());
});

$.post('URL da página PHP', {'soma':sum1})
.done(function(data){
//callback
});
```

Ou por GET

```
var sum1 = 0.0
$('.class_nao_pago').each(function()
{
    sum1 += parseFloat($(this).text());
});

$.get('URL da página PHP', {'soma':sum1})
.done(function(data){
//callback
});
```