# Como passar as variaveis dinamicas de uma url para o php via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Antes de mais nada ja procurei em varios outros posts sobre o assunto aqui e nao encontrei o que necessito, meu cenario é o seguinte estou gerando varios links EX:

desafio.php?id=2&nome=joao

desafio.php?id-3%nome=jose

e estou precisando passar isso via ajax para minha pagina php que processa isso. porem a pagina nao esta pegando os dados o que pode ser? segue meu codigo

urls geradas
       `<a id='desafiar' href='desafiar.php?idd={$linha['id']}&d={$linha['username']}'></a>`

script

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#desafiar").click(function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $( this ).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                 cache: false,
                type: "POST", 
                 url: "desafio.php", 
                data: {url},
                success: function( data ){
                $("#resultado").html( data );
                }
              });
    });
 });
```

na pagina que pega o php

```
  $iddesafiante = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $desafiante = $_SESSION['username'];
  $iddesafiado = $_GET['idd'];
  $desafiado = $_GET['d'];
```

aberto a sugestoes

Comment: Possível duplicata de [enviar a variavel de javascript para php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110484/enviar-a-variavel-de-javascript-para-php)

Comment: Estás a usar ` type: "POST",` no JavaScript e `$_GET` no PHP. Tens de usar o mesmo nos dois.

Comment: @KhaosDoctor votei por deixar aberto, por que apesar do problemas parecerem, são coisas distintas, no link que colocou o problema é "enviar a variavel", no caso aqui a dificuldade é com GET e POST, o que torna um problema diferente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás a usar `type: "POST",` no JavaScript e `$_GET` no PHP. Tens de usar o mesmo nos dois.

Se não estás a usar o link dessa ancora então sugiro usares outra maneira para passar esses valores. Podes ter um json no HTML assim:

```
<a id='desafiar' data-idd="{$linha['id']}" data-d="{$linha['username']}" href='desafiar.php'></a>
```

Assim faz mais sentido para mim, e depois podes usar

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#desafiar").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var data = this.dataset;
         $.ajax({
             cache: false,
             type: "GET",
             url: "desafio.php",
             data: data,
             success: function(data) {
                 $("#resultado").html(data);
             }
         });
     });
});
```

Comment: Entendi aqui a parte da data-variaveis dentro do link entendi, mais no ajax  na parte data:{}; ficaria somente somente data:{data} mesmo? essa  var data = this.dataset; ja deixa no formato pronto?

Comment: @ArsomNolasco na verdade deve ser só `data: data,`, corrigi. Sim o `.dataset` já é um objeto (DOMString) e o jQuery converte no formato necessário.

Comment: posso estar passando quantas variaveis quiser atraves da data- dentro do link?

Comment: @ArsomNolasco sim.